# php include all images of different folders and subfolders

Tags: php, html, web, include

The following script works:

```
$dir = "images/";
$images = glob($dir."*.jpg" );
foreach( $images as $image ):

  echo"<li><img src='". '/' . $image . "' /></li>";
endforeach;
```

Problem is in the PHP script below.Not including more directories where pictures are present

```
$dir = "images/images2/";
$images = glob($dir."*.jpg" );
foreach( $images as $image ):

       echo"<li><img src='". '/' . $image . "' /></li>";
endforeach;
```

how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a subpath when you're using the images too:

```
$subpath = "images2/";
$dir = "images/" . $subpath;
......
echo ".....<img src='/" . $subpath . $image . "' />....";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the full path in

```
$dir = "images/images2/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator) in combination with [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/recursivedirectoryiterator)

```
$path = realpath('/path/you/want/to/search/in');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
               new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), 
               RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    if($object->getFilename() === '*.jpg') {
        echo $object->getPathname();
    }
}
```

Additional reading:

- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html

Comment: Problem is .htaccess he is made problems, and url rewrite.